# all images disappear when i deploy my vue js app on netlify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-deployment, vuejs3

I have a todo-list app I tried deploying it on Netlify it got deployed but all images disappeared I don't know why, NOTE: this is my first time using Vue js or any framework.
, NOTE: when I run serve everything shows just fine,

Here is how I used the images

```
:root {
      --bg-mobile-light: url("~@/assets/bg-mobile-light.jpg");
    --bg-desktop-light: url("~@/assets/bg-desktop-light.jpg");
    --theme-icon-light: url("~@/assets/icon-moon.svg");
    --check-icon: url("~@/assets/icon-check.svg");
    --bg-mobile-dark: url("~@/assets/bg-mobile-dark.jpg");
    --bg-desktop-dark: url("~@/assets/bg-desktop-dark.jpg");
    --theme-icon-dark: url(" ~@/assets/icon-sun.svg"); 
}
.dark {
    --header-img:var(--bg-desktop-dark);
    --theme-icon:var(--theme-icon-dark);
    --header-img-mobile:var(--bg-mobile-dark);
}

 .light {
    --header-img:var(--bg-desktop-light);
    --theme-icon:var(--theme-icon-light);
    --header-img-mobile:var(--bg-mobile-light);
 }

.header {
    background-image: var(--header-img);
}

.themeSwitch-label {
    background-image: var(--theme-icon);
}
```

Comment: Does it working in relative or with the `@` only at the beginning of the file ?

Comment: could you give a link of that deployed app ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim https://musing-sammet-282a70.netlify.app/ here it is

Comment: @kissu only with ~@ at the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images are working and included, but the issue is that the `.dark` or `.light` classes aren't being applied.

Looks like you have a `theme` value set in your local storage that is not present on the netlify app.

Replace

```js
const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme')
```

with

```js
let theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
if (theme !== 'dark') theme = 'light'
```

this will ensure that there always is a default, and only allows `light` or `dark`

Comment: what would be inside the switchTheme?

Comment: my bad, leftover from copy-paste. `switchTheme` does not need to be updated

Comment: can you clarify which part doesn't work? All the script is intended to do is make sure this line runs `body.classList.add(theme)` with either with either `light` or `dark` as the `theme` value. It doesn't update the localStorage

Comment: it doesn't apply either `dark `or l`ight `when I open `localstorage` in the browser it shows `light` but it's not applied

Comment: did you update the netlify app? still shows the same code. If the theme is preset to either 'light' or 'dark' it seems to be working without any changes, so the suggested code change only addresses the _initial_ value, it does not affect localStorage.

Comment: check it out is it working? https://inkabuse-todo-list.netlify.app/

Comment: yes, you should be able to validate by clearing localStorage